# Trouble with Proving the One-Point Compactification of $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, open-map, compactification

I am trying to prove that the one-point compactification of the interval $(0,1)$ with the Euclidean Topology is $S_{1} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$ and I am having some trouble getting there.

The process I am going by has two steps:

1. Show that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $S_{1} - \{ (1,0)\}$
2. Show that the one-point compactification of $S_{1} - \{(1,0)\}$ is $S_{1}$ itself.

Right now, I am stuck on Step 1:

What I did was I set up a mapping $g: (0,1) \to S_{1} - \{ (1,0) \}$ defined by $g: x \mapsto (\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2 \pi x)$.  Now, I need to show that $g$ is a homeomorphism.

To show that $g$ is onto, I said that if we let $X:= \cos 2 \pi x$ and $Y:= \sin 2 \pi x $, $X^{2}+Y^{2} = (\cos 2\pi x)^{2} + (\sin 2 \pi x)^{2} = \cos ^{2} 2\pi x + \sin^{2} 2 \pi x = 1$, so every point on the unit circle is given by $(X,Y)$. The only point on the unit circle we are not including is $X=1$, $Y=0$, but the preimage of this point under $g$ would be the point $x = 0$, which is not included in the domain. Therefore, the range consists solely of the image set of $g$, so $g$ is onto.

To show that $g$ is one-to-one, literally what I did was, I drew graphs of the sine and cosine functions from $0$ to $2\pi$ side-by-side on the same plot, and pointed out that as the parameter $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $X = \cos 2\pi x$ ranges from $\cos (0) $ to $\cos (2 \pi)$ and $Y = \sin 2 \pi x$ ranges from $\sin (0)$ to $\sin (2 \pi)$. Looking at the graphs, we see that for no $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$ do we obtain $(\cos (2\pi x_{1}), \sin(2 \pi x_{1})) = (\cos (2 \pi x_{2}), \sin(2 \pi x_{2}))$, so clearly $g$ is one-to-one as well.

**I feel as though these two proofs are too handwavey - could anyone provide me with more rigorous looking way of proving these things?**

Really, though, what I wanted to ask about is showing that $g$ is continuous and an open map. If I can show these two things, I can show that $g$ is a homeomorphism and thus I will have part 1 completed. However, normally, to show that $g$ is continuous, I would take an arbitrary open set in the range, so an arbitrary open set in $S_{1}-\{ (1, 0) \}$ and show that its preimage is also open in the interval $(0,1)$. T**he problem here is that I don't know what an arbitrary open set in $S_{1}-\{ (1,0) \}$ looks like! Can somebody please show me how to prove this part?** I imagine that once I've seen what this proof is supposed to look like, showing that an open set in $(0,1)$ maps to an open set in $S_{1} - \{(1,0)\}$ won't be too hard. Although, if you want to provide me with a proof of that too, I won't complain!

Thank you ahead of time for your help and patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdoff space, and let $x_0$ be any point of $X$.
Then $X$ is the one-point compactification of $X-\{x_0\}$. So to show $S^1$
is the one-point compactification of $(0,1)$ all you need is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $S^1-\{(1,0)\}$. As you say $f:t\to (\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t)$ is a continuous bijection. So you want the reverse to be
continuous.

Define

$g_1:\{(x,y)\in S_1:y>0\}\to(0,1)$ by $g_1(x,y)=(2\pi)^{-1}\cos^{-1} x$,

$g_2:\{(x,y)\in S_1:x<0\}\to(0,1)$ by $g_2(x,y)=1/2-(2\pi)^{-1}\sin^{-1} y$,

$g_3:\{(x,y)\in S_1:y<0\}\to(0,1)$ by $g_3(x,y)=1-(2\pi)^{-1}\cos^{-1} x$.

These are continuous, defined on open sets, match up on where each is
defined, and so glue together to form a continuous map $g:S^1-\{(1,0)\}\to(0,1)$. This is inverse to $f$.

Comment: I didn't say that $f$ was a continuous bijection. I was able to show that it was a bijection, but I was never able to show that it was continuous because I didn't know how to. That's primarily what I was asking about.

Comment: also what do you mean here by $\{1\}$? $S^{1}$ is supposed to be the unit circle, so that point on the unit circle does $\{1\}$ refer to here?

Comment: if you could modify your answer to actually show that $f$ is continuous, that would be awesome.

Comment: @ALannister The continuity of $f$ is just continuity of sine/cosine.

Comment: I thought that didn't necessarily translate to a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose instead we remove $(0,1)$ from $S^1$ and consider the sterographic projection $f:S^1-{(0,1)}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-y}$ which is a homeomorphism (you should check this, but it is very standard).

Can you show that $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: Sterographic projection proves that $S^1-{(0,1)}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic. Then showing that $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic gives you your desired homeomorphism.

Comment: Oh that's a typo. I said the right thing first and then wrote the wrong thing afterwards

Comment: that's better but I'm having a hard time seeing how that map is onto. EVERY real number has a pair $(x,y)$ such that $\frac{x}{1-y}$ equals that real number?

Comment: I suggest you go look at how the map is constructed to see why the map is onto. Just google sterographic projection.

Comment: I'm trying to find information about the sterographic projection of a circle onto a line but all I'm finding is a sphere onto a circle.

Comment: @ALannister Draw a line from the north pole $(0,1)$ through a point $(u,v)$ on the circle and a point $(t,0)$ on the $x$-axis. Can you use geometry to determine $t$ from $u,v$ and vice-versa?

Comment: @ALannister Using intermediate algebra. Tomorrow I am teaching my intermediate algebra students about lines - slope, point-slope form and slope-intercept form. These are the necessary ingredients for determining $t$ from $u,v$ and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Any set of decreasing small open balls around each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives a base of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So take such a base with all the open balls small enough.

The topology on $S^1-\{(1,0)\}$ is generated by the intersection of these open balls with it. So we get a base for its topology. If you draw a picture of these open balls intersecting with $S^1-\{(1,0)\}$, you'll see that they are made of either one or two "open intervals" in $S^1-\{(1,0)\}$. Their preimages by $f$ on $(0,1)$ are clearly open, so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I honestly am having an extremely hard time visualizing this. Is there a way you can formulate this to make it less visual and more set theoretic?

Comment: I honestly suggest you to try to visualize more, but OK. Use open squares of side length less than $1/2$ as the base of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then you can calculate what the intersections of these open squares with $S^1$ would be and write down their formulas explicitly. Remove $\{(1,0)\}$ from the intersection, and that's what you'll end up with.

Comment: I'll try, but this answer sounds so foreign to me - nothing like I thought it would be. I was told by my prof this problem was supposed to be easy. But, this is turning very hard very fast.